# How do I get each individual line out of a pysimplegui multiline input?

Tags: multiline, pysimplegui

I am trying to use a list of emails inputed into a multiline in pysimplegui and one at a time run through a script to modify the account from our website. I am not sure how to pull each email separately to run a for loop.

```
layout = [
    [sg.Text('batch customer account edit software. First copy and paste your list of emails you would like to have edited,')],
    [sg.Text('then select either delete (and keep contents), or turn off emails.')],
    [sg.Button('Delete Accounts', key='-DEL-'), sg.Button('Unsubscribe', key='-UNSUB-')],
    [sg.Multiline(key='-Input-', size=(80,40))],
]

window = sg.Window('Account Editor', layout)

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == '-DEL-':
        deleteCheck = sg.popup_yes_no('Are you sure you want to delete these accounts?')
        if deleteCheck == 'Yes':
            emails = values['-Input-']
            for line in emails:
                DeleteAccounts()
        else:
            break
```

I haven't completed the code completely but I need to grab each email individually first to slowly work my way through the rest. I am a beginner!

Comment: Line splitted by `'\n'` in the content of Multiline element, try `emails = values['-Input-'].strip().split('\n')`

Comment: Thank you! I actually didn't need the '\n' in the content. just using the .strip().split() did the trick!

Comment: You can also set the parameter `rstrip=True` when you create the `Multiline` element which will do the `rstrip` for you.

Comment: If is not provided then any white space is a separator.